# How to determine if an object is a collection of objects implementing a common interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method which returns true when a PropertyInfo instance references an object that is a collection of IDataExtractor objects:

```
    private bool IsCollectionOfIDataExtractors( PropertyInfo propInfo )
    {
        var result = false;

        var extractors = propInfo.GetValue(dataExtractor, null);

        if (typeof ( ICollection ).IsAssignableFrom(extractors.GetType() ) ||
            typeof ( ICollection<> ).IsAssignableFrom(extractors.GetType() ) )
        {

            IEnumerator extractor = ((ICollection)extractors).GetEnumerator();

            extractor.MoveNext();

            if (typeof ( IDataExtractor ).IsAssignableFrom(
                extractor.Current.GetType()) )
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When thinking about this method I searched through StackOverflow and found the following related item [Accessing a Collection Through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104603/accessing-a-collection-through-reflection/549212#549212) .  That got me half way there.

After some testing it looks like this works, but I'm not 100% convinced.  I'm working up beefier tests.

I'm curious though, is there a better way to implement this method?  I don't really like the cast statement,

```
IEnumerator extractor = ((ICollection)extractors).GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: What is it that you don't like about the cast, exactly?

Comment: I always try not to cast if I can help it.  I realize that in the body of the if I've already checked assign-ability.  But I'm not sure if typeof(ICollection<>) is true then does the cast work?

Comment: I'm adding tests now to verify all this.  My more general question is what I'm really interested in, does anyone know of a better way to implement this method?

Comment: Yes.  `ICollection<>` implements `ICollection`, so the cast won't fail.  But if it were me, I would do an 'as' cast to and test for `null`.  I would also probably test/cast for `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection`, unless there's something very specific about the `ICollection` interface that you require.

Comment: @Toby, `ICollection<T>` does not guarantee implementation of `ICollection`.  The BCL collections implement both, but custom collections may or may not implement both.

Comment: Note that in this case, the correct cast is `IEnumerable` as `IEnumerable<T>` types _are_ guaranteed to support `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var extractors = propInfo.GetValue(dataExtractor, null);
var asEnumerable = extractors as IEnumerable;

if (asEnumerable != null)
{
    var enumerator = asEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();

    if (enumerator.Current != null)
        return enumerator.Current is IDataExtractor;
}

return false;
```

Comment: It occurred to me as I was writing this that if the collection is empty, you'll have a harder time determining its member types, *and* your original code will throw a `NullReferenceException` at `extractor.Current.GetType()`.

Comment: Thanks, this reduced the size of my code and made it easier to understand.  Thank you Toby.

Comment: Just be aware that not all objects that implement `ICollection<T>` will necessarily implement `ICollection`.  The same is true of `IList<T>` vs. `IList`.

Comment: I've rewritten using IEnumerable instead of ICollection since both ICollection and ICollection<> implement it.

Comment: @Dan: D'oh, you're right.  I'm so used to seeing them implemented side-by-side that in my head the `ICollection` was an "inherited" interface.

Comment: @Martin: I've rewritten my code to use IEnumerable, as well, thanks.